# How do I add additional days to NSDate depending on a few parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I'm attempting to create a fetch date that has a few parameters and I'm getting a bit confused about my logic here.

User case #1:

- Create 3 objects in the same day

  - fetch date = 1 day later, 2 days later, 3 days later

User case #2:

- Create another object the following day

  - fetch date = 4 days later (from original date) because there will be prior fetch dates to account for

User case #3:

- Create another object in 4 days from original date

  - fetch date = 1 day later from creation date (5 days from original date)

Here's what I have so far:

```
- (NSDate *)createdAtDate {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    return now;
}

- (NSDate *)fetchDate {
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSUInteger count = [[RecordingController sharedInstance].memos count];
    dayComponent.day = count;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    return nextDate;
 }
```

Basically, I'm counting every instance being saved into core data and making that be the amount of days later, but this can become a problem if there are many objects being saved because the fetch date continues to increment.

The issue I'm attempting to solve is that if the object is created on a different day or if there are no other objects that are "queued" (awaiting to be fetched), it won't calculate the fetch date correctly with my current code.

Comment: You neglected to mention what issue you have with the code you posted.

Comment: Oh, the issue is that if the object is created on a different day or if there are no other objects that are "queued" (awaiting to be fetched), it won't calculate the fetch date correctly with my current code.

Comment: Update your question with those details so people don't have to hunt through the comments.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create NSFetchRequest
2. Sort fetchRequest by fetchDate, descending
3. Limit fetchRequest to 1 object
4. Execute fetchRequest

The one object you have in that array contains the last fetchDate. I guess you then have to branch if the fetchDate you got is older than today.

1. if fetchDateOld <= today, fetchDateNew is tomorrow
2. if fetchDateOld > today, fetchDateNew is fetchDateOld + 1 day